# how to properly secure google maps javascript api key or any api key for that matter?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The page here outlines most of the info https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037, It says

- Do not store API keys in files inside your application's source tree --> *I understand this*
- Do not embed API keys directly in code --> ???

the 2nd point above is not very clear. The javascript api key needs to be in javascript code and will obviously be public as anyone can view the source of a html page.

Then how can I secure my api key in such a case?

Comment: Control the allowed referrers to be domains you control